# SyncedFlush and RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I just shifted from 7.6.2 to 8.6.2 with Elasticsearch, and I wanted to continue to use the RestHighLevelClient. After doing some research, I found out about compatibility mode, and read that this was a way to make it all work. After transitioning over, I created 2 beans that set up RestHighLevelClient in compatibility mode, but I keep getting an error message on build talking about syncedFlushRequest class not being found. After searching through the files there was no direct use that I could see, and the stack trace brought me to the .build() line from the RestHighLevelClientBuilder. Could you explain why I keep getting this error? I even tried setting an enviornment variable called ELASTIC_CLIENT_APIVERSIONING to true.

Nothing seems to be working and I have been stuck trying to get this issue fixed for almost a week, can you help me with this? If you guys need any more information or resources please let me know and I will provide any details as needed.

For more context:

Error creating bean with name 'rhlClient' defined in class path resource [reasourcename] : failed to initiate [org.elastocsearch.client.resthighlevelclient]:

Factory method 'rhlClient' threw exception with message: org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/flush/SyncedFlushRequest

I tried searching for all flushes used, and there is no direct use of a syncedFlush.

I tried compatibility modes and looking through and updating all POM.xml dependencies to newest version.